# Using Maven-3 Got Http 409 error when re-deploy with archiva

Tags: http, maven-3, archiva

I am deploying jar file to maven repository (archiva)

### pom.xml :

```xml
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>      
    <id>archiva.internal</id>
    <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    <name>Internal Release Repository</name>
    <url>http://server:8080/archiva/repository/internal</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>archiva.snapshots</id>
    <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    <name>Internal Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>http://server:8080/archiva/repository/internal/snapshots</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

### settings.xml:

```xml
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>archiva.internal</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
        <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>archiva.snapshots</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
        <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
    </server>

</servers>
```

First maven deploy is success,

```xml
Uploading: http://server:8080/archiva/repository/internal/com/test/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: http://server:8080/archiva/repository/internal/com/test/maven-metadata.xml (306 B at 2.4 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.843s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 07 17:09:49 EST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/11M
```

If I try to redeploy the same artifact I get:

```xml
Failed to transfer file: http://server:8080/archiva/repository/internal/com/test.jar. Return code is: 409 -> [Help 1]
```

Is it possible to redeploy the same artifact with the same version, or do I have to manually delete the artifact from archive prior to re-deploy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As an administrator, go to the repositories page and edit the managed repository `internal` - there you can uncheck *Block Re-deployment of Released Artifacts*.

However, I wouldn't recommend it in general. Once something is there, it can be downloaded. Once it is downloaded, it can be cached by Maven. If you change it, you won't know that the "real" release is being used everywhere.

Version numbers are cheap - it's better to use a new one.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't really a solution, Brett. This is just a workaround. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: can you clarify, @mschonaker? The 409 is a feature when redeploying an existing artifact - the only way to prevent it is to disable the feature, or to delete/re-add as the original poster said. In either case I don't recommend it, and instead suggest deploying with a new version number.

Comment: You're not inquiring into the cause of the problem and your solution is based on a conjecture. Today I found that the 409 was thrown due to file permissions.