# HTTP Status 409 - The target deployment path [...] does not match the POM's expected path prefix

Tags: maven, xsd, artifactory

I use Artifactory as a Maven Repository, on which I'm not admin (corporate repo).
I'm trying to use XmlSchema (through many dependencies of appfuse-basic-struts archetype) but I'm face of an issue that I am not able to understand when I run ***mvn package***:

> **HTTP Status 409 - The target deployment path 'org/apache/ws/commons/XmlSchema/1.1/XmlSchema-1.1.pom' does not match the POM's expected path prefix 'org/apache/ws/commons/XmlSchema/SNAPSHOT'. Please verify your POM content for correctness and make sure the source path is a valid Maven repository root path.**
>
> type Status report
>
> **message** The target deployment path
> 'org/apache/ws/commons/XmlSchema/1.1/XmlSchema-1.1.pom' does not match
> the POM's expected path prefix
> 'org/apache/ws/commons/XmlSchema/SNAPSHOT'. Please verify your POM
> content for correctness and make sure the source path is a valid Maven
> repository root path.
>
> **description** The request could not be completed due to a conflict with
> the current state of the resource (The target deployment path
> 'org/apache/ws/commons/XmlSchema/1.1/XmlSchema-1.1.pom' does not match
> the POM's expected path prefix
> 'org/apache/ws/commons/XmlSchema/SNAPSHOT'. Please verify your POM
> content for correctness and make sure the source path is a valid Maven
> repository root path.). Apache Tomcat/6.0.18

Even in transitive dependencies, I don't find it.
Can anyone explain me what the trouble ?

I found this post [Using Maven-3 Got Http 409 error when re-deploy with archiva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043457/using-maven-3-got-http-409-error-when-re-deploy-with-archiva) but it does not seem to match my issue.

**EDIT 1** : this work quite well when I don't use my corporate repo.

**EDIT 2** : Here the view of the repo via http :

```
Index of repo/org/apache/ws/commons/XmlSchema/1.1

Name                     Last modified      Size

../
maven-metadata.xml->         -    -
maven-metadata.xml.md5->     -    -
maven-metadata.xml.sha1->    -    -
XmlSchema-1.1.jar        18-Sep-2006 20:12  124.96 KB
XmlSchema-1.1.jar.asc->      -    -
XmlSchema-1.1.jar.md5    18-Sep-2006 20:12  32 bytes
XmlSchema-1.1.jar.sha1   18-Sep-2006 20:12  40 bytes
XmlSchema-1.1.pom->          -    -
XmlSchema-1.1.pom.md5->      -    -
XmlSchema-1.1.pom.sha1->     -    -
```

**EDIT 3** : Dependencies

```
mvn dependency:tree

[INFO] com.edf.dpi.esip.gdt:gdt-ihm:war:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.appfuse:appfuse-struts:war:2.0-m5:compile
[INFO] +- org.appfuse:appfuse-struts:warpath:2.0-m5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.appfuse:appfuse-web-common:war:2.0-m5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.appfuse:appfuse-web-common:warpath:2.0-m5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.appfuse:appfuse-service:jar:2.0-m5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.3.0-beta2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- net.sf.jsr107cache:jsr107cache:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- velocity:velocity-dep:jar:1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-all:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-aegis:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:20040917:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-ws-security:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- xfire:opensaml:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:133:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- xml-security:xmlsec:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- wss4j:wss4j:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-core:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1-beta-9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  |  \- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.apache.ws.commons:XmlSchema:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-java5:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- xfire:xfire-jsr181-api:jar:1.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-generator:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-jaxb2:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |        \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-xmlbeans:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- xmlbeans:xbean:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-annotations:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- commons-attributes:commons-attributes-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     +- ant:ant:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     \- qdox:qdox:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-jaxws:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  |     \- javax.xml.bind:jsr173_api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-spring:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:2.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.directwebremoting:dwr:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- struts-menu:struts-menu:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- velocity-tools:velocity-tools-view:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- opensymphony:clickstream:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- opensymphony:oscache:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- opensymphony:sitemesh:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.tuckey:urlrewrite:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- opensymphony:xwork:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- opensymphony:ognl:jar:2.6.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0:system
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.struts:struts2-codebehind-plugin:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.struts:struts2-spring-plugin:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- displaytag:displaytag:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.acegisecurity:acegi-security-tiger:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.acegisecurity:acegi-security:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.appfuse:appfuse-hibernate:jar:2.0-m5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.appfuse:appfuse-data-common:jar:2.0-m5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.2.1.ga:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.1.ga:compile
[INFO] |        +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:compile
[INFO] |        +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |        +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |        +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |        \- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.0.5:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] +- jmock:jmock:jar:1.1.0:test (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-mock:jar:2.0.8:test
[INFO] \- org.subethamail:subethasmtp-wiser:jar:1.0.3:test
[INFO]    \- org.subethamail:subethasmtp-smtp:jar:1.0.3:test
```

Comment: As stated in the error, the dependent POM file is being deployed to the GAVC coordinates of 'org.apache.ws.commons:XmlSchema:1.1', but the contents of the POM actually declare coordinates of 'org.apache.ws.commons:XmlSchema:SNAPSHOT'. Have you run 'mvn dependency:tree' to try and find where it comes from?

Comment: Yes, but I missed it. I redid the job and really looked for it : 
org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-java5:jar:1.2.6:compile
--> org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-core:jar:1.2.6:compile
--> org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-all:jar:1.2.6:compile
--> org.appfuse:appfuse-service:jar:2.0-m5:compile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transitive dependencies have practically been poisoned.

The best thing you can do is check if the original POM of *'XmlSchema'* has been publish with the version *'SNAPSHOT'* or not. If it has, ask the project maintainers to ***correct this mistake and re-publish the POM***; If it hasn't been published this way, ***remove the incorrect POM file*** and make sure that you ***resolve it again from a healthy source***.

If both of these options aren't applicable, you can download the POM file, edit to correct and redeploy it to your local repository

Comment: As soon as I'm not able to test anymore, I will accept this answer. It seems correct to think that were a publication issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and I was able to get around it by checking the "Supress POM Consistency Checks" check box in the Artifactory remote repository settings.

[maven repo settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztfws.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error: the official pom of XmlSchema v1.1 is wrong, there is no healty source you can get it from so you have the following options:

1. correct it by hand on artifactory,
2. copy it by hand to your local repository (no changes needed),
3. upgrade to a more recent version (since it is a transitive dependency of xfire 1.2.6 this could be not possible, but you can try).

For more info see the answer to [this post](https://getsatisfaction.com/sonatype/topics/invalid_version_in_xmlschema_1_1_pom_xml): Maven Central Repository admins know that the pom is wrong but they cannot correct it and Apache doesn't support XmlSchema 1.1 anymore.

Furthermore this is not the only problematic pom: also Apache commons-logging v1.1 is wrong (it lists wrong dependencies), so I always use v1.1.1 or above.